# How long do files stay in the documents directory (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, caching

If I save a file to the documents directory in a folder, how long does it stay on the disk? Forever (in that case I would have to delete it manually if I wish to do so) or it is deleted every time the app closes?

Comment: The files in the documents directory remain until the user deletes the app (or you delete the file)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Files in the `documents` directory will persist until either the user deletes the app, resets their device or you remove the files in code. Also note however that the contents of the `documents` directory are backed up by iTunes so could persist longer than you would otherwise expect.

On the other hand, the `tmp` directory is not so persistent and its contents won't necessarily survive an app relaunch (they're also not backed up by iTunes) so you could use this if you don't want persistant storage. `/Library/Caches/` is similar in that it isn't backed up but it is persistent. From the docs regarding `tmp`:

> The system will periodically purge these files [in the `tmp` folder] when your app is not running; therefore, you cannot rely on these files persisting after your app terminates.

Basically, if you want to store something for a short period and it doesn't matter if it's deleted by the OS, use `tmp`. If you want something that will persist app launches and whatnot but still won't be backed up via iTunes, use the `cache` folder in Library. It you want something that persists and is backed up, use `documents`.

**Extra info based on comment**

If the images should disappear when the app is relaunched then you should use `tmp`. But take note that the `tmp` directory is not guaranteed to be cleared on an app relaunch. It's certainly possible that the images will still be there the next time you load the app. It's a bit of a gamble really. If it is *vital* to kill the images then wipe them manually somewhere suitable:

```
NSArray* tmpDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:NULL];
for (NSString *file in tmpDirectory) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), file] error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: thanks Gordonium, excellent reply! Follow Up: I have some downloaded images that I want to "cache"/store on disk for the time that the app is running. If the app relaunches, those images should be gone. Do you think the tmp/ folder is better or the Library/Caches/ one?

Comment: @west123 I would say that `tmp` is more appropriate if the images shouldn't survive an app relaunch but you might have to wipe them manually if necessary as the OS may or may not delete them. To explain, I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks again! Here is what Apple says: "On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. This will never occur while an app is running.". While there are no guarantees for NSCache(),  here Apple guarantees me that the Cache directory will not be deleted as long as the app is running. So basically, I have a guarantee that both of these directories will not be deleted as long as I am running. If I manually delete a chosen directory at app launch, would you not agree that the folder choice here is not relevant anymore?

Comment: ok, I see:). Basically I just need a guarantee that the system does not purge a directory DURING Runtime... Anyways, thanks for your time; helped me a lot in my decision making.

Comment: Some will say that 'tmp' can be cleared at any time but the docs specifically say "The system will periodically purge these files when your app is not running; therefore, you cannot rely on these files persisting after your app terminates." Note: "when your app is not running." You could be safe and choose 'Library/Caches/' but I've never had a problem with runtime problems and 'tmp'.